# Solr multiple facet dates

Tags: solr, faceted-search

According to the [Apache Solr documentation on facets](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Date_Faceting_Parameters), I can use keys because: 'This can be helpful when faceting on the same field multiple times with different exclusions.'

I need them because I want to have a facet that gives me 'Last day', 'Last week', 'Last month' options.

However, when I specify a query with the following options set:

```
http://URL/select?
...unrelated...
facet=true&
facet.date={!key=some_key}created&
f.some_key.facet.date.start=NOW/DAY-1DAY&
f.some_key.facet.date.end=NOW/DAY&
f.some_key.facet.date.gap=NOW/DAY+1DAY
...unrelated...
```

Solr complains about:

> [exception] =>
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   Missing required parameter:
>   f.created.facet.date.start (or
>   default: facet.date.start)

When I set facet.date.start, or f.created.facet.date.start, they will override the fields of my some_key (start/end/gap) and this is useless because I need multiple keys... Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Due to limitations of the library I am using, this needs to be done in a single query.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use facet queries:

```
http://URL/select?
...unrelated...
facet=true&    
facet.query=[NOW-1DAY TO NOW]&
facet.query=[NOW-7DAY TO NOW]&
facet.query=[NOW-1MONTH TO NOW]&
...unrelated...
```

Comment: Managed to hack it in using copyFields instead, and no time to change at this point, but this seems like a reasonable solution as well. Have some reputation! :)

Comment: Although the solution works, it is important to not that the filter cache will never get hit due to the "NOW". LucidWorks suggests an alternate approach at http://searchhub.org/dev/2012/02/23/date-math-now-and-filter-queries/ that more or less achieves the same result but allows the query to use the filter cache.